# Subclass of UIPageControl refresh only after uiscrollview move, not before

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, subclass, uipagecontrol

the problem I've met today is with my subclass of `UIPageControl`. When I initialize it, the frame (specifically the origin) and image of dots stays default, which is the problem, since I want it to change right after initialization. However, when I move with scrollView (as in "touch and move") after initialization, they (the dots) somehow jump to the right position with correct images.

What could be the problem?

Code:

CustomPageControl.m

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    activeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"doton.png"];
    inactiveImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dotoff.png"];

    return self;
}

- (void) updateDots
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.subviews count]; i++)
    {
        UIImageView *dot = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        if (i == self.currentPage) dot.image = activeImage;
        else dot.image = inactiveImage;
        [dot setFrame:CGRectMake(i * 13.5, 1.5, 17, 17)];
    }    
}

- (void)setCurrentPage:(NSInteger)currentPage
{
    [super setCurrentPage:currentPage];
    [self updateDots];
}

@end
```

ChoosingView.m - init part

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 300)];
[scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[scrollView setDelaysContentTouches:NO];
[scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:YES];
[scrollView setClipsToBounds:NO];
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
[scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];

pageControl = [[CustomPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 300, 80, 20)];
[pageControl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
pageControl.numberOfPages = 6;
[pageControl setCurrentPage:0];
```

the last line is when I would expect the `UIPageControl` to refresh, however that does not happen.

Comment: I think the problem has to do with timing of your requests: for example, not all subviews have been placed into `self.subviews` array. I would try to move the `[pageControl setCurrentPage:0]` call into your view controller's `viewWillAppear` and see what happens.

Comment: Well, that helped, partially. Images are now correct, but the frames are still wrong, before first move. Thanks though !

Comment: @dasblinkenlight's suggestion probably applies to most of the problems you have... including the frames.

Comment: Well, it probably applies to most of my problems, however, what to do when I use only one viewController in my app, and switch all the views in it? So there is no parent viewController of my pageControl.. So, should I use another viewController, should I re-write my pageControl to 'UIControl' completely or is there another way (something like "change that ; to : and you are ready to go !")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this happen with the standard UIPageControl implementation?

Your problem states that your objects subViews (eg the UIImageViews) rects/size are not initialising to your desired size/position.
I implemented this code in my project with a nib rather than programmatically and I needed to call -(void)updateDots to set it as its initial condition was the standard dots..

I dont see how the UIScrollView has any bearing impact on this unless somehow its linked to your -(void)updateDots function (E.g. your setting the currentIndex of your custom page control). You state, "However, when I move with scrollView (as in "touch and move") after initialization, they (the dots) somehow jump to the right position with correct images."
Because they "jump to the right position with correct images" it means that your -(void)updateDots function must be getting called. I dont see any other explanation.

Also your iteration loop assumes that all the UIViews in your .subViews array are UIImageViews, although fairly safe to assume this, I would check to see if the UIView is a UIImageView with reflection.